# How to open ~~~.sublime-package file?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and I can't open ~~~.sublime-package files.

When I open it with Sublime Text 3, it looks like this:

```
504b 0304 1400 0000 0800 9496 084d 8c0b
5989 b600 0000 0501 0000 0a00 0000 2e67
6974 6967 6e6f 7265 358e c16a 0331 0c44
effa 0a43 6f81 557f 2297 420a 8524 a752
8a62 2bae a9d7 32b2 b224 7f1f 3b9b 5c84
f466 18cd 06eb eddb cb0f 6cd0 e61d 9578
```

The file is longer than that of course, but anyway, I can't read it.

How can I read and edit this file?

Comment: The answer below is correct (i.e. it's just a zip file with a different extension) but note that editing a package directly is not a good idea; in most cases you risk the likelihood of your changes being unceremoniously thrown away when you least expect it.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thank you for your comment. You said that editing directly isn't good idea. Then how can I edit it not directly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `sublime-package` file is just `zip` file with the extension changed; i.e. if you have a tool that can open a zip file, you can open the package and review the contents using it. This may or may not require you to temporarily rename the file to have `zip` extension, depending on the tool.

That said, modifying a `sublime-package` directly is only recommended and safe when you're the one that created the file in the first place; otherwise you run a risk of your changes getting lost when you least expect it.

To explain why, a little background. To begin with, there are two places where a `sublime-package` file can exist.

The first is in a folder named `Packages` that's inside of the installation folder for Sublime itself (i.e. where the executable is). These are referred to as `Shipped` packages because they ship with Sublime and are accessible to everyone using Sublime.

The second is in a folder named `Installed Packages` which is contained in your user specific Sublime `Data` folder. This location varies by platform but you can always find it by selecting `Preferences > Browse Packages` and then going up one folder level. Packages here are referred to as `Installed` packages and are packages that you yourself installed in Sublime. Generally speaking packages here are installed by `Package Control`.

When Sublime Text is updated to a new build, it replaces all of the `Shipped` packages with (potentially) entirely new `sublime-package` files in order to update them.

Similarly, when Package Control upgrades a package, it throws away the old `sublime-package` file and replaces it with a newer version.

This all boils down to the following: ***Never*** directly modify a `sublime-package` file that you yourself didn't personally copy into the appropriate location, or at some point in the future your changes will be unceremoniously wiped away during a package upgrade.

So that leaves the question of how to actually modify a package file when you need to, and the answer is to create an `Override`.

There is a folder called the `Packages` folder which you can get to by selecting `Preferences > Browse Packages` from the menu. This folder can also contain packages, but here they are `Unpacked`; that is instead of having a file named `MyPackage.sublime-package` that contains some files, there would instead be a folder named `MyPackage` that contains files.

As Sublime is going through a `sublime-package` file loading up the files that it contains, it looks in the `Packages` folder to see if there is a folder there with the same name as the `sublime-package` file; if there is, ***and*** there is a file inside of that folder that has the **exact** name and path of the file from the `sublime-package`, Sublime will load it instead of the one from the `sublime-package` file.

For example; assume there is a package named `Foo.sublime-package` that contains a file called `foo.py`; as Sublime is scanning through `Foo.sublime-package` for files it should load, it notices that there is a `foo.py` file. So it checks to see if the file `Packages/Foo/foo.py` exists, and if it does, it loads that file and ignores whatever was inside of the `sublime-package` file.

The contents of the `Packages` folder is not touched during upgrades of packages that are stored as `sublime-package` files, so this means that if you create an `Override` in this manner, your change will persist even if the underlying package upgrades.

The easiest way to create such an Override is to use [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer). With this package installed, you can use `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` from the command palette to easily open any file from any package, and saving the file will make `PackageResourceViewer` automatically create the override for you.

With all of this said, an important caveat; whereas modifying a `sublime-package` directly will cause your changes to be unceremoniously thrown away without any warning, creating an override will cause Sublime to always use it ***even if*** the package is modified.

Depending on the file and the modification, this can be important. In the example above, if you created an override on `foo.py` to change something about it and then the author of the `Foo` package made changes to `foo.py` to fix a bug or add more features, when the package updates your changes aren't lost but they also will stop the changes in the update from taking effect.

The [OverrideAudit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit) package can help here; one of the things it does it check on upgrades to see if you have an override of a file in a package that was upgraded and warn you so that you can check and see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I can understand what you said. It helped me a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The file you are trying to open is basically an archived package or a zip file (just not with the usual naming convention)

You may need to extract the zip or store it in the correct location so that Sublime Text Application can use them.

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/packages.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I can't understand what your saying. I understand that the file is similar with zip file, but I can't understand how to open and edit the file.

Comment: @OdatNurd has mentioned the package you need. You need to use a package viewer to bypass the restrictions to look inside, the below link should help (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand what I should do.